# Django get next object given the current object in a queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a chapter model so  in the chapter detail view i want the user to be able to navigate to the next and to previous chapter given the current chapter that  he's viewing so what's is the most efficient way to that in django

this is my chapter model

```
class Chapter(models.Model):

    title         = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug          = models.SlugField(blank=True,null=True,)
    module       = models.ForeignKey(Module,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,)
    content       = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
         return self.title
    

   

i have seen some answers while they use the python list method to turn the queryset in to an array but i think maybe there is a better way
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be careful about using id as a positional identifier, as that is only dependable if chapters are created consecutively - you can't create one module of chapters, then another, then add a final chapter on the first module, and you can't rearrange chapters later. I'd extend the model to include a order field, unique for module

in your model

```
ordering = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            fields=["module", "ordering"], name="unique_order_in_modules"
        )
    ]
```

Then you *could* define a get_next_chapter method (get previous chapter would work similarly)

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
... fields
    def get_next_chapter_url(self):
        next_chapter_index = self.ordering + 1
        next_chapter = Chapter.objects.filter(module = self.module, ordering = next_chapter_index).first()
```

But...while this will work, each reference to it is another database call. To be more efficient, you could utilise the ordering number in your view to get all the relevant chapters in a single query, eg:

views.py

```
def view_chapter(request, module_id, chap_num):
    #define vars
    chapters = [chap_num - 1, chap_num, chap_num + 1]
    prev_chapter = None
    chapter = None
    next_chapter = None

    #perform single query
    queryset = Chapters.objects.filter(ordering__in=chapters, module_id=module_id).select_related('module') 
    #I've thrown selected_related in so you can use things like chapter.module.name in your template without additional database calls.
    
    #define context vars
    for chapter in queryset:
       if chapter.ordering == chap_num:
           chapter=chapter
       elif chapter.ordering == chap_num - 1:
           prev_chapter = chapter
       elif chapter.ordering == chap_num + 1:
           next_chapter = chapter

    context = {"chapter": chapter, "prev-chapter": prev_chapter, "next_chapter": next_chapter}
```

and then in your template

```
<a href="{% url 'view chapter' chapter.module_id prev_chapter.ordering %}"> previous chapter</a>
```

Comment: thank you, what if I create a position filed in the chapter  model and then filter  the queryset  by the position and not by id  I think it's  more simple and efficient

Comment: Exactly.  that's what's happening above with ordering__in=chapters....ordering is basically another word for position. It's also filtering by module_id - because the assumption is that modules contain chapters like a book does. With an ordering/position field you can also use it to order_by a queryset to create a module's table of contents, so it can potentially do a lot of work.

Comment: oh yes i did not get that the first very clever thank you

Answer (score 2):

I thought about pagination but I wrote the fastest way.

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True,null=True,)
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,)
    content = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_next(self):
        return Chapter.objects.filter(id__gt=self.id).order_by('id').first()
```

in HTML

You need to call `get_next` in chapter objects loop. I suppose your chapter URL as `detail/<id>`

```
  <a href= {% url 'detail' obj.get_next.id }}> next chapter </a>
```

Comment: You assume that `id` always increments with one. What if some object's been deleted? `Chapter.objects.filter(id__gt=self.id).order_by('id').first()` is a safer approach

Comment: @AlirezaFarahani you are right. I didn't think deeply. I edit the answer now

Answer (score 1):

You can provide them in a context of detail view. For example like previous_chapter, current_chapter and next_chapter as follow

```
class ChapterDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Chapter
    template_name = 'chapter_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'current_chapter'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['previous_chapter'] = your_previous_chapter_link_if_any_else_none
        context['next_chapter'] = your_next_chapter_link_if_any_else_none
        return context
```

Another approach may be defining urls in models.py as follow

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    # ... your models field
    def get_next_chapter_url(self):
        next_chapter = Chapter.objects.filter(id__gt=self.id).order_by('id').first()
        if next_chapter:
            return reverse('chapter-detail', kwargs={'id': next_chapter.id})
```

And in chapter detail page template assuming context object name as current_chapter

```
<a href="{{current_chapter.get_next_chapter_url}}">Next Chapter</a>
```